# mysql AND vs JOIN outputting duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I don't have much experience with sql statements so I'll appreciate if you can review my setting below and let me know the best way to write my SELECT statement. I have multiple tables that I query but for some odd reason, the results I get are duplicates. table_1 is the main table and I am using its fk to reference other tables pk. In my SELECT statment, I am looking for a way to join all tables based on fk value ('item_b_value')

```
table_1
item_a pk
item_b fk

CONSTRAINT fk_table_2_b FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table_2(item_b)
CONSTRAINT fk_table_3_b FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table_3(item_b)
CONSTRAINT fk_table_4_b FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table_4(item_b)

table_2
item_c 
item_b pk

table_3
item_e 
item_b pk

table_4
item_n 
item_b pk
```

This SELECT Statement output duplicates don't know why

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.item_c, table_3.item_e, table_4.item_n
FROM table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4
WHERE table_1.item_b=table_2.item_b=table_3.item_b=table_4.item_b = 'item_b_value'
```

But, if I put AND between each value in WHERE, the duplicates go away.

```
WHERE table_1.item_b= 'item_b_value',
AND table_2.item_b= 'item_b_value',
AND table_3.item_b= 'item_b_value',
AND table_4.item_b= 'item_b_value'
```

Can someone explain this behavior please?

Comment: you have to use group by to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using INNER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.item_c, t3.item_e, t4.item_n
FROM table_1 t1 INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.item_b = t2.item_b
INNER JOIN  table_3 t3 ON t1.item_b = t3.item_b
INNER JOIN  table_4 t4 ON t1.item_b = t4.item_b
```

Comment: Thanks, inner join seems to do the trick as well as listing AND many times as I indicated in my question. However, I am looking for an easier way to get it done. So is inner is easiest way to get it done?

Comment: Yes @Moe, It should be better , Join is used for such cases,  another advantage, it's more readable than comma seperated tables! ..  as  your way is mentioned as bad habit >> Read this article https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this!!